# How to hide empty UITableViewCells showing in UITableView with plain style - IOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

UItableView is showing with empty rows like below...

[image]

how to hide it without changing the tableview style. Do I need to resize the table View, if so how can I know the height exactly to set.

Comment: Are this really emtpy Cells or just the repeating LineSeperator?

Comment: only two rows added.. Empty

Comment: @SAMIRRATHOD I can do, but empty white space should not come for my case, only content should show like in grouped style. I can't use group style because of its width, row should touch both end.

Comment: I have did it different way... Its works fine, but I am not sure its proper way... I have added an image for uitableviewcell with seperator, and hide the separator in table view and given clear background color for table, so rows added will have separator and empty will not have anything... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you add UIview in footer of uitabeview use of  xib or tableview delegate method

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
 return 1;
}
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section; 
{
 return yourview; 
}
```

Comment: I thought like too.. Do you have any idea how to calculate height based on rows... Rows height may differ.

Comment: try dynamic height for example :- 

 CGFloat cellHeight = 0;
    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(310,9999);
    
    CGSize expectedLabelSize = [strmsg
                                sizeWithFont:DEFAULT_FONT(DEFAULT_FONTSIZE)
                                constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                                lineBreakMode:0];
    
       
        
    cellHeight= ( expectedLabelSize.height + CHAT_NAMEFRAME_HEIGHT + CHAT_TIMEFRAME_HEIGHT );
return cellHeight;

Comment: You don't need to calculate the height. It just add a 1px height view at the bottom of your section. Then there won't appear any useless Line-Seperators.

Comment: UIView *view=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:[(CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 1)) ];
return view ;
you add this view in viewForFooterInSection method

Comment: You should also add `[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor ClearColor]];`

Comment: I have did it different way... Its works fine, but I am not sure its proper way... I have added an image for uitableviewcell with seperator, and hide the separator in table view and given clear background color for table, so rows added will have separator and empty will not have anything... :)

Comment: this works once the table loads but I still get empty cells with separators before the table actually populates with my real cells. it's like i'm not sizing the table properly or I need to hide it before it's loaded....

Answer (score 6):

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init];
```

Comment: This is the real answer (in iOS 7, at least). Simple and fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What I had done in one of my projects was to set the tableview's background color to clearColor and separator to none.

Comment: I need separator b/w real rows.

Comment: @Newbee Try setting the tableviewcell background color to gray and layout your content such that they don't cover the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Just drag and drop a view from object library to the TableView empty shell in storyboard. Make the view as footer of the table view (in document outline drag it below the cell's if it is not already at below) make the height of the view '0'. You will not see the view in storyboard because its height is '0' but when its runs it will hide the cells. I think that should work.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you put some logic into your

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

function?

Just return the number of cells which are really filled with data

Comment: will it reduce empty Cells?

Comment: The idea is just to avoid creating empty cells. The number returned by the function mentioned above is the number how often `cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets called.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for plain style table. The table defaults with a bunch of empty cells with line separators (if you've give the lines a colour). Even if I eventually only return 2 rows, it still has a bunch of trailing empty looking cells with line separators. There should be a way to apply line separator style to just the cells I return...

Comment: @tote did you find a solution to the problem with empty cells in a UITableView?